# SQL Server, Select CASE with different casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, casting

I want to do a select that do a cast only for a specific ID but it doesn't seems to work.

Example :

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN(@ID <> 1) THEN Code
    WHEN(@ID = 1) THEN Cast(Code AS int)
  END Code FROM ....
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: I still get the error : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ASS2902' to data type int even if @ID = 2 but I just want to do the cast for @ID = 1

Comment: It will try to cast anyway. Check update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Check if the **@id** is of type int and if all values of column **Code** can be casted to **int**.

**UPDATE** If you have a value that can't be casted to int, your query won't work.

So you can write 2 different queries.

Smth like

```
IF @id = 1 THEN
 SELECT code ...
ELSE 
 SELECT Cast(Code AS int) as Code
```

Comment: That's the name of the output column. There should be an `AS` before it.

Comment: @Marcelo the `as` is not compulsory.

Comment: I still get the error : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ASS2902' to data type int even if @ID = 2 but I just want to do the cast for @ID = 1

Comment: If 'Code' is already of type 'int', then there is no point to cast it to 'int'. If 'Code' is not of type 'int', then it won't work to cast it to 'int' only in certain circumstances. The overall 'CASE' expression has to have a single type.

Comment: The cast Work for every 'Code' when @ID = 1, in fact my stored procs works when @ID = 1 but failed when it's another @ID but I don't understand why the cast occurs when @ID <> 1

Comment: @Mathieu, it gets two values before evaluating no matter of id

Comment: @hgulyan Thanks it works, really appreciate ! Sorry I cannot vote up cause I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: @Daniel Pratt, some types can be casted to int, by the way. for example, float values (not all surely)

Answer (score 2):

Why do want to do this? A SQL Server expression has a single fixed type. In other words, a single expression can't be `varchar(50)` or `int` depending on how the expression is evaluated. You could cast each case to `sql_variant`, but that may or may not make sense based on what you're trying to do.

**EDIT**

If you are executing this query from a stored procedure, you could create an IF..ELSE block to execute a different version of the query based on the value of @ID. For example:

```
IF (@ID = 1) BEGIN
    SELECT Cast(Code AS int) AS Code FROM ...
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT Code FROM ...
END
```

Comment: +1, for a given `CASE`, all of its `WHEN` s and the `ELSE` must return the same data type.

Comment: It's because the 'Employee code' is a nvarchar in the BD but one of my user use number as 'Employee code' but they are store are nvarchar and now he would like to see his employee order by 'Employee code' but when you sort by 'Employee code' it's an alphabetical order.

So for this precise user I want to order numerically.

Maybe there is a better solution ....

Comment: Thanks it works, really appreciate ! Sorry I cannot vote up cause I'm new on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You could have also written:

```
select case when @ID = 1 then CAST(Code as int) else Code end as Code
    from...
```

By the way, any data containing alphabetic characters won't cast to int.

Perhaps could we better help you if you tell us what you want to achieve, with some sample data provided?

Comment: As I mentioned in a prior comment, the whole CAST expression must have a single type. Because the first alternative of the CAST expression here has type 'int', SQL Server will implicitly convert all subsequent alternatives to int. Even when @ID is not 1, all values of 'Code' will be converted to 'int' and any values of 'Code' that cannot be converted to 'int' will cause an error.